# MySQL queries on multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I know all about joining tables, but I'm having trouble figuring out what to do in this case.

I have a table **`users`** which contains a column called **`user_id`** which is an *integer*.

I have a second table called "follows" which contains a column "user_id" and a column called "follow_id". This table is used to log which other users each user follows (think Twitter).

I have a third table called **`posts`** which contains a column called **`user_id`** ,  which is a foreign key.

Ideally I'd like a single query that looks up the **`follows`** table, gets all the **`follow_ids`** from for a *single user,* then returns all **`posts`** from the **`posts`** table.

Comment: Please add some sample data and results ;).

Comment: We cannot answer your question unless you give us more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    follows.follow_id, 
    posts.*
FROM 
    follows 
    LEFT JOIN
    post ON posts.user_id = follows.user_id
WHERE 
    follows.user_id = <UserID>
```

Comment: Your query doesn't quite work for me, but LEFT JOIN looks exactly like what I need. Cheers.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an ON included after the LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Almost got it! It should be 
SELECT 
    follows.follow_id, 
    posts.*
FROM 
    follows 
    LEFT JOIN
    posts ON posts.user_id = follows.follow_id
WHERE 
    follows.user_id = <UserID>